# cl-format reuse the previous parameter

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

Is there a way to avoid duplicating the `1` in the following line using [`cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format)?

`(cl-format true "line~p: ~d\n" 1 1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (format t "line~p: ~:*~d~%" 1)
line: 1
NIL
CL-USER> (format t "line~p: ~:*~d~%" 2)
lines: 2
NIL
```

(There's also `~n@*` to go to the *n*th argument.)

> #### [22.3.7.1 Tilde Asterisk: Go-To](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cga.htm)
>
> The next arg is ignored. ~n* ignores the next n arguments.
>
> ~:* backs up in the list of arguments so that the argument last
>   processed will be processed again. ~n:* backs up n arguments.
>
> […] ~n@* goes to the nth arg, where 0 means the first one; n defaults to
>   0, so ~@* goes back to the first arg. Directives after a ~n@* will
>   take arguments in sequence beginning with the one gone to.

Comment: Yes – it's called [Go-To.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cga.htm)

Comment: @danlei I added the link and part of the documentation into the answer, since comments can be deleted without record, etc.  I didn't modify any of your original answer text, though.  Hopefully that will make this answer easier to find in the future as a dupe target, too (e.g., when someone asks a similar question, searching for "Tilde Asterisk: Go-To" on Stack Overflow will now find this answer).